# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'; Trying to iterate through for loop in python

Tags: python, blender

I'm trying to adapt a script from [GitHub](https://github.com/oarriaga/beauvoir) to get rid of some errors I'm getting. So far I have mainly changed directories. I just ran into this error and cannot find a solution for my particular problem. Here is the full output of the console:

```
    Blender 2.81 (sub 16) (hash 26bd5ebd42e3 built 2019-11-20 16:31:09)
/run/user/1000/gvfs/ non-existent directory
Read prefs: /home/blender/.config/blender/2.81/config/userpref.blend
found bundled python: /usr/local/blender-2.81-linux-glibc217-x86_64/2.81/python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/blender-2.81-linux-glibc217-x86_64/generate_classification_data.py", line 33, in <module>
    image_generator.render()
  File "/usr/local/blender-2.81-linux-glibc217-x86_64/utils/image_classifier_generator.py", line 74, in render
    for class_name, model_path in self.data.items():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'

Blender quit
```

Here is the code it is pointing to:

```
    def render(self):
        self.set_render_properties()
        for class_name, model_path in self.data.items():
            print(class_name, model_path)
            for num_images_rendered in range(self.num_images_per_class):
                obj = self.construct_scene(model_path, class_name)
                box_coordinates = get_image_bounding_box(obj)
                image_name = self.make_image_name(
                        class_name, num_images_rendered, box_coordinates)
                render_image(image_name)
                delete_scene(self.blender_save_path)
                ".self.data.items()"
```

class_name is an array originating from `shapenet_data_manager.py`, another file used in the script. I cant find any other reference to "model_path", including where it was declared. What I am trying to do is create images through domain randomization, so I am a bit out of my depth as far as the python goes. Thanks for all the help you can provide.

Comment: `items` is a method of a dictionary object.  Some how the variable `self.data` is a string instead of dictionary.  The key is to figure out where that happened.  That must be happening in another method of this class.

Answer (score 0):

As @hpaulj said, `items` is a method of a dictionary, while `self.data` is a string. You need to figure out where `self.data` gets set to a string.

I would start by finding all the places where `self.data` is set, either internally in the object or from outside the object, by printing `self.data` out and seeing what it is.

Please update your answer and comment here if you have any more questions :) Good luck!

Comment: When I put a print statement for `self.data` it does not print anything. It is initialized a couple lines up as `self.data = data`, and `data` is from the initialization of the class. From what I understand, `data` is supposed to be the string containing the path to files. I assume the dictionary is supposed to be of these files. Regardless, `self.data` is being assigned as a string containing nothing. I would like to figure this out so the program can scale better, but for now is it possible to simply input a number or line of code manually instead. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: If `self.data` is being set to `data` and `data` is a string, then `self.data` should also be a string, which seems to be what's happening. What do you want `self.data` to contain?